# Authorization/session in REST application

Tags: java, spring, rest, session

I'm working on Java RESTful application with Spring boot and I'm going to develop the authorization/session part. I read some articles and other questions here, but I'm still confused how I should start the development... How to create the session/authorization part in this kind of applications?? I couldn't find any helpful examples, which would be useful for me... I would like to see simple example with login part, where I could retrieve once the sessionId and then use it in a others calls. Could someone just point me out how to start with this or advice some good tutorials about it?

For the login I should create a valid controller but what should be in the request part and how to handle this in order to remember retrieved sessionId, which will be used in other parts of application?

Comment: oauth2 is your friend

Comment: I';m not sure about it... I dont want to create the authorization server or login with other applications...

Comment: You can use basic authentication...

Comment: Check https://gigsterous.github.io/engineering/2017/03/01/spring-boot-4.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536894/how-to-configure-spring-boot-security-so-that-a-user-is-only-allowed-to-update-t