# Springboot allow access to endpoint if userId matches

Tags: spring-boot

I am following up from this question:

[How to configure Spring Boot Security so that a user is only allowed to update their own profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536894/how-to-configure-spring-boot-security-so-that-a-user-is-only-allowed-to-update-t)

Imagine I had an end-point `/user/edit/{id}`, I want this to be accessible if the user either tries to edit themslves (eg: a user with ID 1 accessing `/user/edit/1` but not being able to access `user/edit/2`) *or*, if they are an admin, to be able to edit any user.

Is there any way I can achieve this in the security configuration?

```
.antMatchers("/user/edit/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

Would restrict this to admin users, I want either admin or the id matching the user's id.

The only thing I can think of is inside the controller having something like

```
@GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public void edit(@PathVariable("id") int id, Principal principal) {

        User u = (User) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(principal.getName());

        if(u.getId() == id || u.getRoles().contains("ADMIN")) {
            //accept uer
        }



    }
```

But I was under the impression we shouldn't encode access logic in our controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use Spring Security's [Method Security Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#method-security-expressions) to do this. Example copied from the docs:

```
@PreAuthorize("#c.name == authentication.name")
public void doSomething(@P("c") Contact contact);
```

Read the sections preceding, as there is some configuration needed. Also note that if an expression is used repeatedly [you can define your own security annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#method-security-meta-annotations).

> I was under the impression we shouldn't encode access logic in our
>   controller?

"Should" is maybe too strong a word, IMHO. Security expressions are powerful, and in theory would allow you to keep all security checks separate from the controller logic. Easier to spot when a check is wrong, or missing. Easier to compare with the Swagger annotations too, if you are using those to document your endpoints.

But it can get trickier when you have to do something like filter rows returned so that the user only sees some of the results. Spring Security can do that using [@PostFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#filtering-using-prefilter-and-postfilter). But sometimes it isn't optimal. For example, if you know that certain rows aren't going to be returned you may be able to run a faster query, rather than filter out rows after the fact.

My first Spring Security project had queries like that, so ever since I have tended to use controller logic instead of security annotations. But that's not a good reason to *never* use annotations! So by all means use security expressions when you can, but if you have trouble with them or other considerations arise, integrating security with your controller logic isn't so bad IMHO.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

To control role access in your controller you can use annotations like @Secured or @PreAuthorize.

To use the @Secured, put in you security config class:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig {
    // ...
}
```

And now you can use it in your controller:

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@PostMapping
public Account post(Account account, double amount){
    // ...
}
```

To use the @PreAuthorize, put in you security config class:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig {
    // ...
}
```

And now you can use it in your controller:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@PostMapping
public Account post(Account account, double amount){
    // ...
}
```

For more information you can [check here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#enableglobalmethodsecurity) the spring docs.

Comment: Thanks, that works for the ROLE_ADMIN, but how can I let a user access the endpoint if their id matches the one provided in the URL?

Comment: You can do like @Bampfer said!